# ng2-bootstrap dropdown not found

Tags: django, angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am having issue in my angular app to include ng2-boostrap. I am constently receiving this error in chrome console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ng/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/dropdown.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Looking at how the ng2-bootstrap module is stored in my directory, it seems to me that zone.js should be trying to load this module instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/ng/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/dropdown/dropdown.module.js
```

Here's my app.module.ts import:

```
import { DropdownModule, TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
/* Stuff */
```

And my systemjs.config

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {


var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'npm:@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
    // ng2-bootstrap
    'moment':                     'npm:moment',
    'ng2-bootstrap':              'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
    'ng2-charts':                 'npm:ng2-charts',
  };

  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: './app/main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    // ng2-bootstrap
    'ng2-bootstrap':              { format: 'cjs', main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'moment':                     { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-charts': {
        main: 'bundles/ng2-charts.umd.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    baseURL: '/ng/',
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

And my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
    "lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "angular-calendar": "0.6.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "angular2-datatable": "0.5.2",
    "angular2-ladda": "^1.0.6",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-toaster": "2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.10",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

**Do you have any idea why ng2-bootstrap dropdown isn't loading?**

Comment: I had a problem with the module not being found after building the app, and had to switch my import in the app.ts file to use the specific import location rather than importing everything from 'ng2-bootstrap'... ergo `import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';  Possibly related?

Comment: @silencedmessage tried it and it didn't work. Posted my solution below. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem in my solution. We were integrating a layout and some components had their imports written as:

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
```

So we changed them to:

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

And it did fix the issues!